# Square object proportional editing's problem

Tags: proportional-editing

I have bevelling my square object,and i want to bend upward both of top and bottom vertices of square object just like this[image]

But instead of first image, i get the result like this[image]

In the first one, both of top and bottom vertices of his square object bend upward in z axis, but in mine, only top vertices that bend upward, the bottom doesn't and both of vertices doesn,t really fully bend like in the first image, only portion of it. Is this some sort of bevelling mistake
or is there another reason for this?

And before i end this, i also want to duplicate the top vertices like this [image]
But i don't know why the result end up like this [image]

How can i fix this mess? here's my blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/136ff1141d514357837b953a31290380

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in *Edit* mode, put your mouse over the mesh and press <kbd>L</kbd> to select the whole mesh, and move it, as you see you have 3 meshes overlapping, only of of these is subdivided. Remove the other ones:

[image]

Comment: oh yeah i forget to check if there is overlapping mesh or not.... thanks